# jquery hover not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm adding new clients with socket messages AFTER domready.
i want to expand them on hover.

read some answers here, but nothing works. i don't know why

i tried

```
socket.on('newStudentJoined', function studentJoined(msg) {
    console.log(msg.student + ' joined the room');
    $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr('class', 'studentIcon closed col-md-2 ' + msg.student)
        .text(msg.student + ' 4r3 g345t g354 g54 ght65 g45t 3f4 f4 f4 534 g534')
        .on('hover', function() {
            console.log('hovering');
            $(this).toggleClass('closed').toggleClass('open');
        })
        .appendTo('#joinedClients');
});
```

and

```
$('.studentIcon').on('hover', function() {
    console.log('hovering');
    $(this).toggleClass('closed').toggleClass('open');
});
```

but not even the "hovering" console log comes out.
the selector is correct, if i log it, it highlights the exact element.
to make sure:

```
<div id="joinedClients" class="row">
    <div class="studentIcon closed col-md-2 test">test 4r3 g345t g354 g54 ght65 g45t 3f4 f4 f4 534 g534</div>
</div>
```

what's wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `mouseover` instead

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.studentIcon',function() {
    console.log('hovering');
    $(this).toggleClass('closed').toggleClass('open');
});
```

OR USE

```
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".studentIcon", function (e) {
  if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
    // check if it is mouseenter, do something
  } else {
    // if not, mouseleave, do something
  }
});
```

> The `.hover()` method binds handlers for both `mouseenter` and
>   `mouseleave` events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an
>   element during the time the mouse is within the element.

Comment: mouseover is dangerous -- it can be fired for each child view that you enter as well.

Comment: not even .on('mouseover' works. this is driving me crazy

Comment: @user3787706 :i have edited the code like this `$(document).on('mouseover', '.studentIcon',function() {
    console.log('hovering');
    $(this).toggleClass('closed').toggleClass('open');
});`   this will surely work

Comment: now it works. thanks man.

is it safe to have the same "toggle-both-classes"-code for both events? or can something go wrong there?

Comment: can you still give your opinion on the last question please? can something break there? like "the mouseleave was somehow not detected and from now on, every mouseenter will CLOSE the div"?

Comment: no ..there wont be ny problem  now since you are using delegate handlers using `document`

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are binding the event before the element in question exists (because you are creating the element with javascript).

You need to either bind the event *after* creating it, or target your listener as follows

```
$('#joinedClients').on('hover', '.studentIcon', function() {
    console.log('hovering');
});
```

Comment: I was just about to update my answer with this when I saw you posted.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498458/jquery-bind-event-after-adding-element-dynamic

Comment: Actually, it's okay to bind an event to the element in this case -- it does exist even if it's not in the DOM yet. Try this out: https://jsfiddle.net/4vxnnbef/2/

Comment: @YoYo It depends on jQuery version.

Comment: this looked nice, but doesn't work.
didn't i add the listener after (or better: *with*) creation with the first snippet? should i write a seperate function?

Comment: Make a https://jsfiddle.net/ with your minimum problem. Are you creating '#joinedClients' with javascript? What version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using JQuery, use .hover() :

```
$('.studentIcon').hover(//stuff);
```

Comment: he wants as delegate handler

Answer (score 1):

'hover' is not an actual event. jQuery provides a helper *function* `.hover(enterfunc, leavefunc)` that is equivalent to:

```
$('#mydiv').on({'mouseenter': enterfunc, 'mouseleave': leavefunc})
```

Comment: See [this documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) for an example of how to use `hover()`

Comment: tried it like this     `$('.studentIcon').hover(function() {
        console.log('hovering');
    }, function() {
        console.log('out');
    });`   nothing happens :/